# I'm getting a 'Incorrect syntax near"

Tags: sql

"Incorrect Syntax near')'" error:

when creating the table below:

```sql
    create table branch_supplier (
    branch_id int,
    supplier_name varchar(40),
    supply_type varchar(40),
    primary key(branch_id, supplier_name)
```

What could be the problem. I'm a beginner in SQL

Comment: You are missing a last `)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an ending ')'

```
create table branch_supplier ( branch_id int, supplier_name varchar(40), supply_type varchar(40), primary key(branch_id, supplier_name))
```